# COUNT y consulta compleja con INNER JOIN. (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las tablas comentario, usuario, spam.

La lógica de negocio, es que simple: un usuario puede realizar comentarios, y esto comentarios puede ser marcados como spam por otros usuarios.

La consulta que deseo realizar debe tener la siguiente estructura:

```
datos de comentarios / datos de usuario quien comentó / "usuario_spam" / spam_total
```

**usuario_spam:** será NULL si yo no he marcado el comentario como spam, o sera mi "id" en caso contrario.

**spam_total:** La cantidad de veces que se ha marcado el comentario como spam.

La consulta SQL que he realizado es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
   comentario.*,
   usuario.*,
   US.id AS usuario_spam, 
   COUNT(spam.id) AS spam_count

FROM comentario 

LEFT JOIN spam ON comentario.id = spam.id_comentario
INNER JOIN usuario ON comentario.id_usuario = usuario.id
LEFT JOIN usuario US ON US.id = spam.id_usuario = 123456 //ejemplo

WHERE
comentario.id_articulo = 11111 //ejemplo

GROUP BY comentario.id
ORDER BY comentario.fecha_creado DESC
```

Al parecer la consulta entre comentarios y saber la cantidad de spam que tiene resulta, sencilla, lo complicado es cuando trato de saber si el usuario que ingresa (123456) ha marcado el comentario como spam.

Ejemplo:

```
-----Usuario--       comentario-      ------spam-------
|____ id ____|    | id__ id_usu.|   |_ id __|__ id_comentario_|__id_usu.._|
|____  1 ____|    | 1 __|  1 ___|   |_ 1 ___|_________1_______|__  3 _____|       
|____  2 ____|    | 2 __|  1 ___|   |_ 2 ___|_________1_______|__  2 _____|
|____  3 ____|    | 3 __|  2 ___|   
                  | 4 __|  2 ___|
```

Suponiendo que la consulta es realizado por el usuario de id = 1.
Los resultando serían:

```
|__ comentario ____|____ usuario ____| ______ usuario spam ___| total spam |
|______ 1 _________|_____   1   _____| ________ NULL _________|_____ 2 ____|
|______ 2 _________|_____   1  ______| ________ NULL _________|_____ 0 ____|
|______ 3 _________|_______ 2 _______| ________ NULL _________|______0_____|
|______ 4 _________|_______ 2 _______| ________ NULL _________|______0_____|
```

Suponiendo que la consulta es realizado por el usuario de id = 3.
Los resultando serían:

```
|__ comentario ____|____ usuario ____| ______ usuario spam ___| total spam |
|______ 1 _________|_____   1   _____| ________ 3    _________|_____ 2 ____|
|______ 2 _________|_____   1  ______| ________ NULL _________|_____ 0 ____|
|______ 3 _________|_______ 2 _______| ________ NULL _________|______0_____|
|______ 4 _________|_______ 2 _______| ________ NULL _________|______0_____|
```

Comment: A que te referis con "saber si el usuario que ingresa (123456) ha marcado el comentario como spam."

Comment: La consulta en cada registro se forma por: datos del comentario y quien lo hace, además quiero saber si "equis usuario" forma parte de lo que han marcado como spam los comentarios que se consultan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay necesidad de hacer un join adicional con la tabla `usuario` para poder determinar si el usuario que ingresa ha marcado un comentario como spam.  Es solo cuestión de usar una función de agregación condicional (como `MAX`):

```
select c.*,
       u.*,
       max(case when s.id_usuario = 123456 then s.id_usuario end) as usuario_spam,
       count(s.id) as spam_count
  from comentario c
  join usuario u
    on u.id = c.id_usuario
  left join spam s
    on s.id_comentario = c.id
 where c.id_articulo = 11111
 group by c.id
 order by c.fecha_creado desc;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/YNSLX32241)</kbd>

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho, esto es lo que buscaba. : )

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar usar un `Distinct` para selecionar los no repetidos y luego contarlos con el `Count`

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(c.id)) AS spam_count
```

Answer (score 1):

Si mal no entiendo lo que estas queriendo hacer es lo siguiente:

```
  SELECT 
       comentario.*,
       usuario.*,
       US.id AS usuario_spam, 
       COUNT(spam.id) AS spam_count

    FROM comentario 

    LEFT JOIN spam ON comentario.id = spam.id_comentario
    INNER JOIN usuario ON comentario.id_usuario = usuario.id
    LEFT JOIN usuario US ON US.id = spam.id_usuario = usuario.id

    WHERE
    comentario.id_articulo = 11111 //ejemplo
    us.id = 123456 

    GROUP BY comentario.id
    ORDER BY comentario.fecha_creado DESC
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, editaré la publicación para explicarme mejor